# Android facebook library sromku get photos returns null

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have been trying to work with a library called sromku (a facebook sdk wrapper) which gives some functionallity with facebook. I am trying to call for user photos and albums but when I get the list its filled with image names but the link is null, any idea how to fix that?